# I can't move the element below the image up with pysimplegui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Suppose you have an image and text in a window, and a button below it. I want to move the bottom button up, but I can't find an effective method. What should I do now?

Example layout code:

```
info_layout = [
            [sg.Image(filename = 'data/img/icon_info.png', pad = ((10,0),(10,0)), key = "icon_image"), sg.Text(text = 'example', font=('Arial', 24), pad = ((20,0),(0,0)))],
            [sg.Button(button_text = 'OK', auto_size_button = False, pad = ((130,0),(20,0)))]
         ]
```

It is possible to move to the right using pad.

(Add:)
It seems that my question was wrong.

This is the result of executing the above layout:

[image: result window]

The execution result I want is as follows:

[image: result window]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe only tkinter code for it,

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

column_layout = [
    [sg.Image(filename = 'D:/logo.png', pad = ((10,0),(10,0)), key = "icon_image"),
    sg.Text(text = 'example', font=('Arial', 24), pad = ((20,0),(0,0)))],
]

layout = [
    [sg.Column(column_layout, key='-COL-')],
    [sg.Button(button_text = 'OK', auto_size_button = False, pad = ((130,0),(20,0)))]
]
window = sg.Window('window', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'OK':
        window['-COL-'].Widget.master.pack_forget()
        window['-COL-'].Widget.master.pack()
window.close()
```

After `OK` clicked,

[image]

Comment: You can do the same thing by making the element invisible and visible again.

Comment: I thought it should be OK by setting `visible` option of `sg.Column`, but not work in layout here.

Comment: I was unable to do it with visibility after I left the comment.  I thought it still moved elements but for some reason, it's not doing that now.